# Android Floating Action Button Opens Small View

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

In the Android App of Inbox by Google, when you press the FAB (Floating Action Button), a smaller view with options pop up. How would i go about implementing this?

[image: floating action button with sub-menu]

[Picture taken on the web version for ease, but the effect and look is the same on the app.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating Action Button for Android based on Material Design specification

https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called the Floating Action Button with Promoted Action for Android (Material Design).  Based on Jerzy Chalupski (futuresimple) project linked above, The following github project provides exactly what you are looking for and more:

https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this, but since every button will have a different form i suggest you to create a custom view which shows just the button and when somebody taps on it, another view is shown (the form), it is easy you just have to extend a viewgroup like `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score -4):

Its a long process, i have followed this tutorial for implementing the same - [Floating Action Button](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/09/android-floating-action-button.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This does not seem to show what the OP is after - FAB popup menues with sub-options. This merely seems to be a basic but custom FAB implementation, for which you are likely better off with the standard Android support library.